# Apache Cassandra: Update value with value of other column in same table

Tags: cassandra

I have a large table with several columns. One of the columns is `created_at`, which is a timestamp.
Now I want to add a new column called `last_activated`. This column should initially be filled with the value of `created_at`.

At first I just altered the table to add the new column -> No problem there
but than I tried

```
UPDATE my_table SET last_activated = created_at;
```

what caused the following problem:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:54 no viable alternative at input ';' (update catalog_item set last_activated_at = [created_at];)">
```

Is this somehow possible to do?

I'm using cassandra 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible. At first place where clause is must with UPDATE